# Safest way to store data from back-end to iPhone

Tags: ios, encryption, cdn, backend

I'm currently having a discussion and would really like some input on this situation. I'm kind of new to this part of programming, but I have this certain scenario: I would like to stream a file from a CDN server to my iPhone and I'm wondering what the best way to secure the file on the backend would be. Would it be a good idea to encrypt the file on the backend and then stream it or would it be better to encrypt the CDN url and and then leave the file un-encrypted? I think its much easier to stream un-encrypted data on iOS but would leaving the file un-encrypted on the CDN server pose an issue? Ideally I wouldn't want these audio files to get leaked or anything. Any input would be great!

Answer (score 2):

Like any other [*security through obscurity*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) measure, encrypting the URL will not work: it would take an ill-intentioned person to sniff the TCP traffic for odd-looking URLs to get unobstructed access to the supposedly "protected" content.

Encrypting the content would work, but it introduces a problem of dealing with encryption keys. To protect your content, you could generate a public key on the client, send it to the server, have the server encrypt the content with that public key before sending it over, and decrypt the content on the client using the private key. You could also use the same encryption key on all clients, but in this case your scheme becomes vulnerable to somebody stealing that key.

There is an easier solution, too: since all you need is a way to protect the content on the way to the recipient device, it is sufficient to set up transport-level security - say, by serving the content only through HTTPS.